# PyLint not recognizing mainloop() member of the turtle module

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

I am trying out the turtle module of python, and though the program is executing correctly, PyLint has been incorrectly marking parts of the program as errors. The program `polygon.py` consists of the following:

```
import turtle 
t = turtle.Turtle() 
t.fd(100) 
turtle.mainloop()
```

This program executes as expected, with the turtle moving forward 100 pixels. However, in VSCode, PyLint underlines `turtle.mainloop()` as an error, saying:

```
Module 'turtle' has no 'mainloop' member pylint(no-member)
```

Additionally, in the actual `turtle.py` module, mentions of `mainloop()` along with some other members are also marked as errors, saying:

```
"mainloop" is not defined Pylance (reportUndefinedVariable)
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling PyLint, although the errors continued to display. How can I fix them, or at least hide them considering the program otherwise works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found a solution for the false-positive no member error. For PyLint, go to the corresponding JSON file and add:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs":[
        "--generated-members"
]
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of the question author.*</sub>